# Prove $\tau$ and the euclidean topology over $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not comparable

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau $ be a topology:
$\tau=\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 | S^1 \subset(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A  ) \}   \cup\{\mathbb{R}^2\}$  where
$S^1=\{  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2=1  \}$

Prove $\tau$ and the euclidean topology over $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not comparable

So I have to prove one is not included in the other, can anyone show me how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A = \{(2,0)\}$, so $(2,0)$ is open and not open in the standard topology. Now take an open ball containing $(1,0)$, it is not open in the topology mentioned.

Comment: "(2,0) is open and not open in the standard topology".... did you meant (2,0) is open in $ \tau $ and not open in the standard topology?. The only sets open and closed in the standard topology are the whole set and the empty set

Comment: Yes, because it does not itersect  $S^1$, so  $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (2,0) $